# Reading MATLAB dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, h5py

I have created several dictionaries using MATLAB, and saved them as `.mat` file using `"-v7.3"` flag (as it has been suggested as a way to read `.mat` files in Python)

My code in MATLAB is:

```matlab
cnn6 = load("imgnet19k_less_feature_map_20230412_alexnet_cnn6_dict.mat");
dictionary_analyze = cnn6.dictionary_imagenames_features;
keys_in_order = keys(dictionary_analyze);
values_in_order = values(dictionary_analyze);
save("cnn6_keys_in_order_imagenet_19k_v2.mat", "keys_in_order", '-v7.3');
save("cnn6_values_in_order_imagenet_19k_v2.mat", "values_in_order", '-v7.3');
```

The dictionaries are structured this way:

[image]
[image]
[image]

In Python, I tried the following code to read these `.mat` files:

```py
import os
import sys
import pickle

import numpy as np
import h5py
import tables
from scipy.io import loadmat

normal_semantic_features_dir = "./normal_semantic_features/"

alexnet_features = ['cnn2', 'cnn4', 'cnn6', 'cnn8']

#dict_cnns = h5py.File(normal_semantic_features_dir + 'cnn2_keys_in_order_imagenet_19k_v2.mat', "r")
f1 = h5py.File(normal_semantic_features_dir + 'cnn8_keys_in_order_imagenet_19k_v2.mat', "r")
f2 = h5py.File(normal_semantic_features_dir + 'cnn8_values_in_order_imagenet_19k_v2.mat', "r")

array_of_keys = dict_cnns['keys_in_order']

print(list(f1.keys()))
```

results:

```py
> ['#refs#', '#subsystem#', 'keys_in_order']


    a = f1["keys_in_order"]
    type(a)

> h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset

    for k, v in annots.items():
        print(k,"........" ,annots[k])
        print("....")

> __header__ ........ b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Fri Apr 14 13:32:47 2023' ....
> __version__ ........ 1.0 ....
> __globals__ ........ [] .... None ........ [(b'keys_in_order', b'MCOS', b'string', array([[3707764736],
>        [         2],
>        [         1],
>        [         1],
>        [         1],
>        [         1]], dtype=uint32))] ....
> __function_workspace__ ........ [[ 0  1 73 ...  0  0  0]]
```

How should I read the contents of these mat files, and convert them to python-style dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `scipy.io`'s `loadmat` function and then iterate through `some_matlab_dict`ionary's `keys` and insert new `keys` and `values` into `some_python_dict`ionary:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat

file_name = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/MATLAB/some_matlab_dict.mat'
some_matlab_dict = loadmat(file_name)
some_python_dict = {}
for key in some_matlab_dict:
    if not key.startswith('__') and not key.startswith('None'):
        some_python_dict[key] = some_matlab_dict[key][0]
```

so from this `matlab` code for saving `some_matlab_dict`ionary `.mat` file:

```
var1 = [1 2 3];
var2 = [11 21 33];
d = dictionary;
d('var1') = {var1};
d('var2') = {var2};
save('C:\Users\ThalamusLab\Desktop\MATLAB Behavioral Tests\SAVE_DATA\some_matlab_dict.mat');
```

`print(some_python_dict)` outputs:

```
{'var1': array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8), 'var2': array([11, 21, 33], dtype=uint8)}
```